# Image files corrupted in ZIP downloaded from GitHub

Tags: image, github, zip

[The linked repository](https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code) has several images that look fine on GitHub, such as [this jpg image](https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code/blob/master/02-collisions/Assets/Images/stars-background.jpg) or [this png image](https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code/blob/master/02-collisions/Assets/Images/spaceCraft6_SW.png).
However, when I download a ZIP file of the repository and unzip it in my Windows 10, all the image files are corrupted - their size becomes only 1 KB!
How can I correctly download this repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

In a terminal which has `git` installed, just run this

```
git clone -b <branch-name> --depth=1 https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code
```

Replace `<branch-name>` with the branch name you want to download the zip for.

---

The repository you have linked uses Git LFS<sup>1</sup> to store binary files. The file extensions stored in such format can be found in the `.gitattributes` [file](https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code/blob/master/.gitattributes). When you download the zip<sup>2</sup> file only [pointer files](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#lfs-pointer-files-advanced) representing the binary files are generated.

You can also identify if a file is managed using LFS in GitHub if you see this :

[image: LFS]

You should be able to get the images using this link format :

`https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/user_name/repository_name/branch_name/file_name`

An example for [this](https://github.com/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code/blob/master/02-collisions/Assets/Images/stars-background.jpg) jpg image would be : `https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/erelsgl-at-ariel/gamedev-5780-code/master/02-collisions/Assets/Images/stars-background.jpg`

To get all the LFS files, you need to clone the repository using [`git`](https://git-scm.com/).

`git clone <repo-link>`

---

<sup>1</sup>Read more about Git LFS in Github [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files)

<sup>2</sup>Read more on LFS files not being included in zip [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/903)

Comment: BTW, the image file in the Zip-ball is replaced by a text file, for instance, for the .jpg image: version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:c8d47415fe807ee00a95f5be7e9e0d7c534acc6b2432592c9d30b34532f00a7e
size 140640

Comment: @Zerte git sees them as pointer files but Git LFS uses this pointer file to checkout/fetch or both i.e pull the original file stored in Git LFS storage